# Mapbox-gl-js - Mouse events are off after applying CSS transform to map

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am using mapbox-gl-js to display a map inside of a responsive container.

Regardless of the size of the responsive container, I want the map to maintain the same resolution such that resizing the window does not affect the bounds or zoom level of the map, it simply scales the map as if it were a static image.

I achieve this by dynamically calculating the scale factor and applying it to the container via CSS transform:

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#map-scaler {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 1280px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#map-container {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


    <div id="map-container">
        <div id="map-scaler">
           <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    // Get size of map container for display
    var mapContainer = $("#map-container");
    var mcWidth = mapContainer.width();
    var mcHeight = mapContainer.height();

    // Get size of scaler container
    var scaleContainer = $("#map-scaler");
    var sWidth = scaleContainer.width();
    var sHeight = scaleContainer.height();

    var scaleWidth = mcWidth / sWidth;
    var scaleHeight = mcHeight / sHeight;

    $("#map-scaler").css("transform", "scale(" + scaleWidth + ", " + scaleHeight + ")");
```

This achieves the desired results visually. For example, I can have a 1280x1280 map displayed inside of a 500x500 container.

The problem is that all the mouse events are now "off".  For example, if you attempt a map click or a scroll zoom, the map applies your mouse event to the wrong area of the map.

How can I compensate for my CSS transform so that mouse events accurately reflect where the user clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the resize method? As mentionned in the doc, the method looks at your div width&height and resize your map. Event should be updated too.

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Map#resize

Comment: this doesn't appear to help, I've got the same problem